# Changing eclipse.ini file downside for less required memory

Tags: android, eclipse, jvm

I installed Eclipse and when I tried launching it it gave me an error :

**Eclipse failed to create java virtual machine**

Since it couldn't allocate the required memory space(1024+512) I changed my .ini file into: (see below)...allocating a memory of only 512+512, and now it's opening...

### My question is: Is there any downside to this change?

**eclipse.ini:**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember having problems with eclipse hanging and not responding and saying max memory size has been exceeded, and I allocate more memory to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, yes, but since with 512/1024 it didn't want to open, what else could I do?

Comment: Check which app is taking all the memory? and what's your memory size?